# Automatizar carga de documento, pasar de word a excel o similar

Tags: base-de-datos, excel, text, ms-word

> Gente, espero que entiendan que esto es una situacion especial. Es una pregunta que no cumple con las reglas, pero ahora mismo el mundo es un desastre y realmente necesito si alguien puede darme una mano con esto. Llenenme de negativos si quieren pero por favor, no cierren la pregunta.

En mi trabajo estamos cargando a mano unos archivos referidos las denuncias reportadas por la gente referidas al COVID-19. El tema es que este virus está creciendo exponencialmente, por lo que nuestro trabajo tambien lo hace, y estamos atrasados con la estadística, en parte por eso la cifra que se conoce sobre los casos es mas baja de lo que en realidad es. Sin mas preambulo, les paso a mostrar lo que tengo:

Nos llega un archivo .doc (pregunte en el chat antes de realizar la pregunta acá, y me preguntaron la version de Word. En realidad trabajamos con distintas versiones, yo en casa tengo la ultima version porque soy estudiante y MS la regala y actualiza siempre, pero en el trabajo tengo el 2010, creo que puede ser indiferente la version ya que yo quiero trabajar con texto, podria inclusive copiarlo y llevarlo a un notepad por ejemplo)

Este archivo .doc tiene unos 100 textos que tienen mas o menos esta forma

> Averig.Ilicito – Pto. Ilícito (COVID-19 Coronavirus) – Femenina Mayor
>   **19/03** – PU.**81027** – Alta **07:06**hs – CP Campana; 05:00hs. Se
>   recepcionó llamado a XXXX (Dda. XXXX 1000), dando cuenta que su vecina
>   XXX, víspera regreso proveniente de Brasil, no cumpliendo con el
>   protocolo de aislamiento.  Personal procedió a brindarle los
>   correspondientes números telefónicos para tales casos, dando aviso a
>   personal de Salud.

Cada uno de esos textos deben ser pasados a tabla en una base de datos, que tiene unos 20 campos. Yo quisiera al menos poder sacar los 3 datos que puse en negrita, que son, la fecha, el numero de Parte Urgenta, que esta siempre despues de `PU.` y la hora, que siempre es la que esta despues de la palabra `alta` (ya que puede haber otras horas en el parrafo, de todas maneras la hora que busco es la primera que aparece, asi que pueden tenerse esos dos criterios, o la primer aparicion, o despues de "alta")

**Si no sabes como hacerlo pero conoces herramientas que puedan hacerlo, tambien me seria de gran ayuda**

La cosa es que estamos pasandolos a mano, y este virus crece a pasos agigantados con ello las denuncias, y no estamos pudiendo cargar esto.

La idea es que cada nuevo texto (podria identificarse por la aparicion de la cadena `PU.`) cree una nueva fila (puede ser en una tabla de excel o de access, da igual) y coloque esos 3 campos.

Espero sepan entender una pregunta excepcional en un momento excepcional.

Comment: Los productos de Microsoft vienen con Visual Basic for Applications. Usado eso podes manipular los documentos como para leer el contenido. No se si podes abrir un doc y un excel a la vez. Pero en todo caso podes generar un txt con campos separados por comas (csv), intermedio, que te haga de interface. En cuanto a identificar lo que queres extraer, lo mas simple sería usar regular expressions (regex) -me parece que es un modulo que se tiene que habilitar aparte-. Dado que el texto que te pasan es desestructurado, es posible que el resultado no sea perfecto.

Comment: Claro eso es cargado a mano por otra gente y suele tener errores, por eso unicamente mi idea es extraer al menos esos 3 datos, y y de ser posible la fecha. Con eso aliviaria a la mitad nuestro trabjao. Voy a leer sobre eso, muchas gracias

Comment: Agustín, no estoy seguro si la comunidad puede llegar a aceptar una pregunta tan amplia, pero obviamente dadas las circunstancias, tal vez se puedan "relajar" las reglas de forma temporal. Mientras tanto, te comento, tienes dos problemas distintos (a) como extraer los textos de los documentos Word (b) como extraer los datos de cada texto. El primer problema es complejo por las distintas versiones de word que tienes, ya que hay mucha diferencia entre un doc y un docx que es un formato abierto.

Comment: El problema (b) es un poco más simple, si tuvieras un conjunto de archivos de texto ya convertidos del word, puedes intentar con expresiones regulares para extraer cada dato. Esto es sencillo de resolver con python, te propongo una solución al respecto: https://repl.it/@pmoracho/WordExtract

Comment: Cualquier cosa sigamos en el [chat] por obvias razones estaré conectado todo el día.

Comment: @Podría hacerse con una macro en VBA. Si vuestras versiones de Excel y Word son 2007 o superior, aun siendo un DOC, lo estás abriendo desde MS-Word, que es lo que importa. Pero la macro solamente serviría si el patrón de datos (la estructura que has explicado) es la misma todo el rato. ¿Puedes compartir un Word con datos de ejemplo, aunque sean Falsos? Es para poder hacer pruebas.

Comment: Gracias a todos, a traves del chat un usuario me mostro algo que empezo con javascript (que ademas me viene muy bien porque es el lenguaje que mejor entiendo) y extrajo todo correctamente. Me dijo que en cualquier momento me iba a facilitar el codigo a traves de una respuesta, asi que les agradezco las ideas y el tiempo a todos, de corazon. Pero voy a esperar a tener ese JS, hasta entonces voy a seguir cargadno a mano. @PatricioMoracho me hizo un script en python que esta muy bueno, pero me deja casos afuera(la busqueda me arroja 58 apariciones de la cadena ``PU.`` y el script arroja 47 lineas

Comment: y no pretendo molestar a nadie para que haga las cosas, sabiendo que otra persona tambien lo esta haciendo, me parece un abuso, asi que no mencione lo que me pasaba con el python, mas que nada porque preferiria modificarlo yo a mi gusto en lugar de andar molestando con cada cambio que surga (en mi trabajo siempre surgen cambios) entonces creo que voy a optar por esperar la respuesta en ``js`` ya que, como dije, es un lenguaje que entiendo y puedo editar. Nota mental: Luego de la cuarentena, aprender PYTHON con urgencia

Comment: una vez mas les agradezco a todos por hacer esto (opinar, explicar, codificar, responder, darme opciones) sin ningun interes mas que un "gracias"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Una aproximación, usando JavaScript (NodeJS) es crear un `script` que haga un análisis del documento de Word (`.docx`) y escriba el resultado en un libro de Excel (`.xlsx`).

He implementado este código de forma muy rápida para intentar aportar una solución al problema, entiendo que es para un caso de urgencia.

Necesitas:

- [Node.JS](https://nodejs.org/es/)
- [ExcelJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs)
- [word-text-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/word-text-parser)

No hago comprobaciones entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, esto es una primera aproximación a una posible solución.

Usando el módulo `word-text-parser` obtenemos los párrafos del documento de Word.

Filtramos cada párrafo para quedarnos con aquellos que contengan exclusivamente las cadenas: *PU.* y *Alta*

También creamos una expresión regular para obtener la fecha, la cual asumimos siempre con el siguiente formato: *XX/XX*. Donde XX son dígitos numéricos del 00 al 99. (No se valida si una fecha es válida, por lo tanto 12/03 será válido así como 03/12).

Luego cada párrafo lo separamos en palabras, y buscamos las palabras que deseamos de acuerdo a los criterios antes mencionados.

Cada valor se coloca en un objeto con la siguiente estructura:

```js
{ PU: <cadena>, Alta: <cadena>, Fecha: <cadena>}
```

Se guarda una lista de dichos valores y se genera un libro de Excel usando la librería ExcelJS.

El código final puede verse así:

```js
const path = require('path');
const wordParser = require('word-text-parser');
const ExcelJS = require('exceljs');


/* La siguiente función se encarga de crear un documento de Excel
* a partir de una lista de datos recibida como parámetro
*
* @input dataList [Array]: Array con datos: { PU: <cadena>, Alta: <cadena>, Fecha: <cadena>}
*/
const createWorkBook = function(dataList) {
  if(!dataList || !Array.isArray(dataList) || !dataList.length) return;
  let wb = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
  wb.created = new Date();
  wb.creator = 'Someone';
  wb.views = [
    {
      x: 0, y: 0, width: 10000, height: 20000,
      firstSheet: 0, activeTab: 1, visibility: 'visible'
    }
  ]
  //creamos la hoja del libro
  let dataSheet = wb.addWorksheet('Data');

  //20 campos por registro, es lo que estableces en tu pregunta
  // los 3 datos van en las columnas 3, 5 y 7. con PU, alta y fecha respectivamente.

  // creamos la cabecera de datos
  let columnHeaders = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    let header = {header: `Dato${i}`, key: `Dato${i}`, width: 30};
    if(i === 3) {
      header.header = 'PU';
      header.key = 'PU';
    }
    if(i === 5) {
      header.header = 'Alta';
      header.key = 'Alta';
    }
    if(i === 7) {
      header.header = 'Fecha';
      header.key = 'Fecha';
    }
    columnHeaders.push(header);
  }
  dataSheet.columns = columnHeaders;

  // Recorremos la lista y almacenamos los registros en la hoja
  dataList.forEach(data => {
    dataSheet.addRow({PU: data.PU, Alta: data.Alta, Fecha: data.Fecha});
  });

  // Escribimos el archivo resultante:
  wb.xlsx.writeFile(path.join(__dirname,'test.xlsx'))
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Done');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(`Algo salió mal: ${error.message}`);
  });
}

/*
* La siguiente función analiza los párrafos capturados del archivo de Word
* y devuelve una lista con los datos obtenidos de los mismos
* @input resultsList [Array]: Array con cadenas correspondientes a cada párrafo del archivo
* @output data [Array]: Array con datos: { PU: <cadena>, Alta: <cadena>, Fecha: <cadena>}
*/
const parseResult = function(resultsList) {
  if(!resultsList || !Array.isArray(resultsList) || !resultsList.length) return;

  // filtramos los párrafos que contengan "PU." y "Alta"
  const filteredParagraphs = resultsList.filter(p => p.includes('PU.') && p.includes('Alta'));

  // Array que almacenará los datos extraídos
  const data = [];

  // Expresión regular para evaluar la fecha.
  const regexFecha = /^\d\d\/\d\d$/i

  // recorremos cada párrafo
  filteredParagraphs.forEach(p => {
    //creamos el objeto para almacenar los datos
    let value = {
      PU: '',
      Alta: '',
      Fecha: ''
    }

    // separamos cada párrafo en palabras
    let splitedParagraph = p.split(' ');

    //analizamos cada palabra y capturamos los datos
    splitedParagraph.forEach((word, index) => {
      if(word.includes('PU.')) {
        value['PU'] = word.split('.')[1];
      }
      if(word === 'Alta') {
        value['Alta'] = splitedParagraph[index + 1];
      }
      if(regexFecha.test(word)) {
        value['Fecha'] = `${word}/2020`;
      }
    });

    // almacenamos el resultado en el array
    data.push(value);
  });

  // mostramos los datos por consola
  console.log(data);

  // llamamos al procedimiento para crear el libro de Excel a partir de los datos
  createWorkBook(data);
}

// nombre del archivo a analizar
const fileToParse = path.join(__dirname, 'demo.docx');

// llamamos al analizador del archivo
wordParser(fileToParse, parseResult);
```

En Github tengo un [repositorio](https://github.com/virtualkur2/word2excel) de esto implementado, allí hay 1 archivo Word de prueba (`demo.docx`), que tiene una estructura aleatoria (no estructurada).

Espero que con esto logres avanzar. Cualquier duda lo consultas.

Comment: gracias, estoy instalado todo en un virtualenv para hacer la prueba, puedo estar un rato, pero en breve lo pruebo. Infinitas gracias

Comment: Funcionó de mil maravillas! Ahora me toca trabajar a mi, pero un poco menos :) Infinitas gracias

Comment: Me alegra haber aportado una solución. Saludos y a cuidarse.

Comment: Comentario aparte aprovechando la situacion, los numeros que ven en la tele van con 7/10 de atraso, la situacion es mucho peor de lo que dicen los medios, aunque ya como se ven asusutan. Cuidemonos, hagamoslo por nuestros viejos, tios, abuelos... esto se va a poner feo. Abrazo grande a todos

Answer (score 2):

Con LibreOffice puedes convertir por línea de comandos un .doc a .txt:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to txt:Text archivo.doc
```

A partir de ahí puedes obtener lo que necesitas con expresiones regulares ya sea con la misma línea de comandos o con otro lenguaje de programación. Dividiendo primero el texto por el separador `" - "`. Incluso, los datos que necesitas se podrían extraer desde la base de datos dependiendo de la versión.